# Deployment of ASP.NET MVC web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment

I'm trying to publish my site to the remote host, but I can't find the service URL in the hosting panel.

What should I write in the service URL part to be able to connect to the destination computer, and publish the application on it?

Comment: You should call your hosting provider and ask them.  There's no way we can know.

Comment: I mean what do you usually write in there? in the DNS tab of the hosting panel, i have the site's name, name servers, a host Ip for the site etc. but none of them worked, visual studio always gives me the error "could not connect to the destination computer"

Comment: Again, we don't know how your hosting provider has configured MSDeploy on your server.  Only they know.

Answer (score 0):

The service URL is usually:  https://mywebserver.com:8172/MsDeploy.axd